# When does a SBT package get downloaded/built?

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to use http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html .

The site indicates I must add this to `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies +=  "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "core" % "0.9.1"
```

which I did. I then restarted the play console and `compile`d.

Importing doesnt work:

```
import dispatch._
```

---

Guess I have been silly, but then I never used a build system when using Java.

How must I trigger the process that downloads/builds the package? Where are the jars (or equivalent) stored; can I reuse them? When is the package available for use by the Play application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *doesn't* say you should add it to `project/plugins.sbt`. That is the wrong place. It says to add to the `build.sbt` file, on the root of your project. Being a Play project, `project/Build.scala` might be more appropriate -- I don't know if it will pick up settings from `build.sbt` or not.

To add [the dependency in your Build.scala](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/SBTDependencies):

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "core" % "0.9.1"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to run sbt update.

From the sbt [Command Line Reference](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Command-Line-Reference):

```
update Resolves and retrieves external dependencies as described in library dependencies.
```

Comment: Sorry. I just re-read the question and it seems like you're trying to use dispatch in a play application. In that case it probably belongs in the project/Build.scala file in the appDependencies list. Try `play update` after that.